# bugzilla configuration on apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, bugzilla

I have a problem with the bugzilla and restarting apache2. When i try to reload apache2 it says:

**The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.**

The file configuration for bugzilla is:
ServerName www.bugzilla.sphinx.al
ServerAdmin elio.pashaj@sphinx.al
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html

Can u help me with
 Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites enabled/bugzilla.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory

Answer (score 0):

In your conf file, point your DocumentRoot to **/var/www/html**

Also Add the following directives to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla/  (**Note**: This is where your bugzilla is installed, if under html directory, this would be /var/www/html/bugzilla/ )

```
<Directory /var/www/bugzilla> 
<br/>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
<br/>
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
<br/>
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
<br/>
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options AuthConfig
</br>        
</Directory>
```

Restart your apache and hope thiis helps